# Bump sample code for BUMPCHAT not working

Tags: android, bump

In the BUMP API I CANT ABLE TO RUN BUMPCHAT SAMPLE CODE.
My API key is correct.
In the logcat this error.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1703): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bumptech.bumpapi.BumpResources$layout
```

Will anyone help me about that issue.

Thanks

Comment: hey can you plz tell me about bump aap?i got this from github but i dont understand that my phone is connected to bump while do the bump on two phones or not?can u plz give some code or demo like you have implemented.plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have different package name in the layout which you are referencing in the XML from the layout class

> E/AndroidRuntime(1703): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.bumptech.bumpapi.BumpResources$layout

your application is not able to find this class `com.bumptech.bumpapi.BumpResources$layout`

Which means that the `layout` class is inside the `BumpResources` class.

Check the layout and specify the correct package name.

Comment: Layout is not a file it is a class which is inside the BumpResources what you have to do is that just check your layout files and if there is any view inflated from the java files provide the true packagename and class file

Answer (score 2):

As a sidebar, I believe that sample was was for version 0.4 of the android API, they're moving to api v3, see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bump-api-android/kQsYiIv0xVo/pwrTtBqB_PsJ

API v3 is on github, and a demo app can be found at https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-android/blob/master/bump-test/src/com/bump/apitest/BumpTest.java